# Exception at ConstructorUNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, salesforce

I've been following this package : https://github.com/davispeixoto/Laravel-5-Salesforce

I know that the packages expected 4 parameters :

```
return [
    'username' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD',
    'token' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_TOKEN',
    'wsdl' => 'path/to/your/enterprise.wsdl.xml',
];
```

---

I provided them everything, and try this

```
try {
    echo print_r(Salesforce::describeLayout('Account'), true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $e->getTraceAsString;
}
```

---

I got

> Exception at ConstructorUNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Navigate to Setup
- In the Quick Find bar, type in Critical Updates
- Select Critical Updates
- Locate the Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections​ under the Update Name column
- Click on Deactivate.

[image]